# Scrollbars on page due to CSS in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've been tying to fix a problem with CSS on my site for a while but am getting nowhere.

This URL http://www.housekeys.co.uk/register.asp in chrome is fine, but in IE and Firefox, I get horizontal and vertical scrollbars but cannot figure out why.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please!

Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `overflow: auto;` on `#main`

```
#main {
overflow: auto; /* remove this */
background: #FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Remove `overflow: auto;`

Also remove `height: 100%;` from `#container` but keep `min-height: 100%;`

```
#container {
width: 770px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 100%; /* remove this */
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vector. I tried removing both but decided to keep 'overflow:auto;' as that caused a different problem across the browser. Just removing 'height: 100%;' made a difference :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. If it helped could you mark the answer as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 100% high div (the one with `#container`) and then another div below that (`#footer`).

My guess is you wanted to put the `#footer` inside the `#container`, below `#main`.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister! I've moved the `#footer` inside `#container` and that's better. It was deliberately outside '#container' as I wanted it (the footer) to sit at the bottom of the window but with it outside `#container` and with the change made re the 100% high div, on pages that had content that did not fill up the whole page, I would get a gab between the bottom of the content and the footer which you can see on this page: [link](www.housekeys.co.uk/about.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I see also in chome

I think it's better

```
#main {
overflow-y: auto; // show if scrollbar required
overflow-x: hidden; //never show X scrollbar
background: #FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion user2706318. I followed one of the suggestions by Vector (above) and Mr Lister below and things are much better now :)